# Уменьшить память занимаемую изображением background?

Tags: android, memory, android-layout

Закинул в папку drawable изображение jpeg 1920x1080 весом 373Кб. Когда задал его фоном для своего приложения через XML, отображение этого фона стало занимать **80Мб** оперативки.

Поискал решение, вычитал что надо кинуть в папку `drawable-nodpi`, что уменьши объем занимаемой оперативы до **16Мб**. Хотя это все равно много, не могли бы Вы написать почему это помогло?

Так же нашел, что-то с `BitmapFactory.decodeResourse()`, но из англоязычных источников разобраться с этим не смог.

Помогите окончательно разобраться с этим вопросом!

Comment: Что-то у меня размеры не сходятся. 1920*1080*4 = 8MB в -nodpi должно быть. Что за устройство? Как вы определяете этот размер?

Comment: Кратко: это pre-scaling (пре-масштабирование), оно не выполяется для изображений в -nodpi. Изображение декодируется в Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 - 4 байта на писель, т.е. для -nodpi будет 1920*1080*4.